# BlobTrigger in Functions Runtime preview 2 with local storage account

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I have the Functions Runtime preview 2 installed . 
I was able to create and run functions with timer trigger. But the Blob trigger doesn't , seem to 'trigger'.
I am using local azure explorer ( local development blob container) as my trigger source. 
Is this a known issue?

i notice that the mouseover in 'integrate' section shows endpoint protocol as https. i specified http endpoint when creating it( since thats what the local storage emulator supports). but runtime seems to be picking up https on its own.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I was able to create and run functions with timer trigger. But the Blob trigger doesn't , seem to 'trigger'.

It seems that the issue is your **storage account connection string**. You only write the Blob endpoint in your connection string. If you don't want to use '`UseDevelopmentStorage=true`', You need to write the complete [connection string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator) instead:

```html
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1;TableEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1;QueueEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10001/devstoreaccount1;
```

You could also check the function logs on your side. Maybe there is an error.

> i notice that the mouseover in 'integrate' section shows endpoint protocol as https

I have tested on my side, the system is based on endpoint url 'http'. Even if the  `DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https`, we still could use the storage connection string successfully. If we set`DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http` and endpoint url to 'https', the connection string would not work.

Comment: I tried all combinations but all i get in logs is  "Invalid storage account 'devstoreaccount1'. Please make sure your credentials are correct.".  Also how do i use the value "UseDevelopmentStorage=true" . Should i add an additional settings.json file with a Values property?

Comment: @zingh If you click Azure function, did you see any app settings?  And in screenshot it seems that you copy connection string to drop down list directly, instead of  choosing the connection name.

Comment: No there isn't anything with the name app.settings. in fact, it doesn't allow me to add a file by that name as well. Thanks.

Comment: The app settings is not a file name. Try to click function lightning icon. In screenshot, you have the value in 'Storage account connection' drop down list. It means you  could set something for drop down list. You could try to store something as  key/value type(connection string name/connection string). Or update your answer to provide screenshot for me, so I can know more details.

Comment: If not, I suppose  because it is a preview version, so there are still something can not support. Myabe you could use Azure Function in VS. Click New project>Cloud>Azure function>choose v1(.net framework template).

Comment: @zingh Please also make sure you have started the Azure Storage Emulator.